# Why does nokogiri put a 113 MB directory in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I'm about to check my project into git and I noticed I have over 14,000 files to commit just for nokogiri. Is there some way to get around this? Or is that just the way it is?

Comment: The answer to this is quite obvious. There's a lot of code involved in nokogirl.

Comment: This looks to be a rails project, why not reference `nokogiri` gem in your `Gemfile`.  It sounds like you checked out the `nokogiri` project into your project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% percent aware of the structure of a Rails app or nokogiri - but it sounds like you want to commit artifacts of an external dependency or library into git.

In general, you can usually avoid this. Others who checkout your repository should be able to restore the artifacts using a command (like 'gem install' or 'bundle install'). Perhaps Rails has a specific command for this as well..

Additionally, you can tell git to ignore certain files and folders which you don't wish to commit into your repo (just search 'git ignore').

Comment: I'm pretty good with git so I know about those options. I guess what I was wondering is why nokogiri installs so many files. I would expect most of that to be in the gem.